# Protobuf-net and Unity3d missing assembly reference to Assembly-CSharp (this project)

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine, protobuf-net

So after a lot of work I have finally discovered my true problem.

Using protobuf-net I compile a DLL serializer, similar to below:

```
 RuntimeTypeModel rModel = TypeModel.Create();

 rModel.add(typeof(AccessList), true);
 //** add more classes from project here... **
 rModel.AllowParseableTypes = true;
 rModel.AutoAddMissingTypes = true;

 rModel.Compile("MySerializer", "MySerializerDLLName.dll");
```

After I get `MySerializer.dll` I add it to the plugins folder, and when I try to use it get `Could not load file or assembly 'Assembly-CSharp [...]'`

I have discovered that this missing assembly is actually the compiled unity c# code.

So my problem is that I need to somehow be able to use `MySerializer.dll` and have it know that it will have the missing dll later, once compiled...

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I finally figured out this problem that has been killing me for awhile..

So the fix is to not to statically reference classes from the dll, rather load them using dynamically.

Here is the code:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("MySerializer, MySerializerDLLName");
RuntimeTypeModel rModel = (RuntimeTypeModel)type.GetMethod("Create", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).Invoke(null, null);
```

I hope this helps someone else...

Comment: I've ran into this issue as well but in a different context. Any idea why would it not accept referring statically to the dll?

Comment: So it's a circular reference issue. I ended up using Delegate.CreateDelegate to dynamically communicate with my assembly http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/925380/circular-references-between-dlls-firstpass-and-a-g.html